# yii2 gridview column headers not translated

Tags: php, gridview, widget, yii2

Currently a problem with getting the headers translated when using the GridView Widget, supplied by Yii themselves.

The page and item indicator and all other features of the page are being translated, and when I build this table without the GridView Widget everything is fine. However now after doing a few tables manually I would like to see if someone knows a solution for this problem.

Just to sum things up:

- i18N is working properly on the entire website
- Translation is not working on GridView Widget
- Translation is working on for example ActiveForm
- All headers are added to the correct Message file.

And Here the corresponding code:

```
//Controller-Action
$releaseQuery = new Query();
    $releaseQuery->
    select("`amount` AS 'Amount', 
            `created` AS 'Created',
            `user`.`email` AS 'User',
            `cinema`.`name` AS 'Cinema',
            `date` AS 'Date'")->
    from("`release`")->
        join('left join', '`user`', '`release`.`created_by` = `user`.`id`')->
        join('left join', '`cinema`', '`release`.`cinemaid` = `cinema`.`id`');
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $releaseQuery,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50,
        ],
    ]);

// View
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            'Amount:currency',
            'Created',
            'User',
            'Cinema',
            'Date',
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if in your model you have the i18n in attributeLabel

like this sample  (if you don'have you must add or add them in label parameter for gridview)

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'name' => Yii::t('app', 'Name'),
        'type' => Yii::t('app', 'Type'),
        'description' => Yii::t('app', 'Description'),
        'rule_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Rule Name'),
        'data' => Yii::t('app', 'Data'),
        'created_at' => Yii::t('app', 'Created At'),
        'updated_at' => Yii::t('app', 'Updated At'),
    ];
}
```

if you generate the model with gii remenber to set i18n checkbox

If you use new column name in query  these became attribute in gridview e you must manager the relative label with proper translation function

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['attribute' => 'Amount',
         'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Amount'),],
        .......

    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: I have the attributeLabels set in the model. However I use a different set of labels with the query. Even though BOTH of there are defined in the message file, I'll try fiddling around with this.

Comment: The name of the column in query became attribute in grdiView not label. I think you must add the label with Yii::t